# Rails MaterializeCSS Passing User.id to Modal

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, materialize

As the title suggests, I've want to use MaterializeCSS Modal to show User data. The problem currently is that though each card has a trigger, All triggers show the same Modal. I'm assuming it's because no object data is being passed through. What is the best method for me to solve this problem? Thank you!

```
           <%@member.each do |x|%>
           <div class="member-card z-depth-2">
             <a href="/users/<%=x.id%>">
             <img src="<%=x.avatar%>"/>
             </a>
             <div class="member-info">
               <strong><%=x.first_name.capitalize!%> <%=x.last_name.capitalize!%></strong>
               <button data-target="modal1" class="btn modal-trigger" id="<%=x.id%>" >About Me</button>
               <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <img src="<%=x.avatar%>" alt="" height="300px" width="350px"/>
                   <h4><%=x.first_name.capitalize!%></h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                   <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <%end%>
```

$(document).ready(function(){

// the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
  $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();
  });

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible associate each div and button and append to page?
The below should append button data-target and div id attributes using user id.

`<%@member.each do |x|%>
           <div class="member-card z-depth-2">
             <a href="/users/<%=x.id%>">
             <img src="<%=x.avatar%>"/>
             </a>
             <div class="member-info">
               <strong><%=x.first_name.capitalize!%> <%=x.last_name.capitalize!%></strong>
            <button data-target="modal<%=x.id%>" class="btn modal-trigger" id="<%=x.id%>" >About Me</button>
               <div id="modal<%=x.id%>enter code here" class="modal">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <img src="<%=x.avatar%>" alt="" height="300px" width="350px"/>
                   <h4><%=x.first_name.capitalize!%></h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-footer">
                   <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
           <%end%>`

#### What changed?

`<button data-target="modal<%=x.id%>" class="btn modal-trigger" id="<%=x.id%>" >About Me</button>
               <div id="modal<%=x.id%>enter code here" class="modal">`